# Report definition file invalid

Tags: c#, winforms, console-application, rdlc, reportbuilder3.0

I have Created a Console application to export Report.rdlc to Output.pdf(This Report.rdlc created using **Report Builder 3.0 as Report.rdl then renamed it to Report.rdlc).I did include Microsoft.WinForms.ReportViewver 9.0.0.0 dll as reference and used LocalReport.Render() method for this purpose.Am using VS2008 and Adventureworks 2008 DB..NET framework is 3.5**

I get an error while compiling as:

```
Error   1   The report definition is not valid.  Details: The report definition has an invalid target namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition' which cannot be upgraded.   C:\Documents and Settings\username\My Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\Rdclrender\Rdclrender\Report.rdlc   Rdclrender
```

I have gone through all the posts in here and msdn website none helped me.

What is the exact cause for the error?

Answer (score 0):

Found a web-link says:

However, I still have the ability to convert the report to RDLC 2008 format which is weird. .NET Framework 3.5 “Microsoft Report Viewer” control doesn’t support RDLC 2008 format in Local mode.

here : http://ahmedelbaz.com/tag/rdlc/